# Bluetoothctl not detecting any bluetooth controllers, worked on Fedora but not Arch

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, bluetooth, thinkpad

Issue: Bluetooth doesn't turn on, no connection can be made.

Evidence:

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

[image: Gnome bluetooth manager showing switch is flipped "on," but nothing happens.]

What I've tried / checked:

- Followed [arch installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth)
- Installed `bluez bluez-utils blueman`
- Restarted `systemctl restart bluetooth.service`
- Checked UEFI for bluetooth hardware enabled
- Checked `rfkill` for blocked hardware, then blocked and re-unblocked bluetooth
- Ran `modprobe btusb`
- Enable `--experimental` flag in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

Useful info:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0489:e0d0 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 27c6:6594 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy A5 (MTP)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. SD Card Reader and Writer
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 291a:8385 Anker Innovations Limited Anker USB-C Hub Device 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:49d9 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Audio
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 320f:5064 SONIX USB DEVICE
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 4-Port hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5271 IMC Networks Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lspci -kv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: fast devsel

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ -2147483648
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 0

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 1

00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26, IOMMU group 2
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fd800000-fd8fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27, IOMMU group 3
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 2000-2fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fd700000-fd7fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28, IOMMU group 4
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 3000-3fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fd000000-fd1fffff [size=2M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 830000000-8301fffff [size=2M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.7 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29, IOMMU group 5
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fd600000-fd6fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 6

00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Device 5095:17aa
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30, IOMMU group 7
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 1000-1fff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fd200000-fd5fffff [size=4M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 860000000-8701fffff [size=258M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel, IOMMU group 8
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 8

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, NUMA node 0, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at fd800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 82, IOMMU group 11
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at fd704000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fd700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm QCNFA765 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device e0be
    Physical Slot: 0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 87, IOMMU group 12
    Memory at fd000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath11k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath11k_pci

04:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at fd600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev d1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 860000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at 870000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Memory at fd500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 85, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at fd5c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, IOMMU group 16
    Memory at fd400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at fd5cc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp

05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 58, IOMMU group 17
    Memory at fd200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at fd300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5096
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 81, IOMMU group 19
    Memory at fd580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_sof_amd_renoir

05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5095
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 86, IOMMU group 20
    Memory at fd5c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

```
$ sudo rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep blue
[    1.227319] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
```

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-11-12 11:42:29 EST; 17min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 636 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 37080)
     Memory: 3.1M
        CPU: 23ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─636 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --experimental

Nov 12 11:42:28 bkeever-arch systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 12 11:42:28 bkeever-arch bluetoothd[636]: Bluetooth daemon 5.66
Nov 12 11:42:29 bkeever-arch systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 12 11:42:29 bkeever-arch bluetoothd[636]: Starting SDP server
Nov 12 11:42:29 bkeever-arch bluetoothd[636]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

```
$ lsmod | grep btusb
btusb                  65536  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                45056  1 btusb
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             942080  15 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
```

```
$ journalctl -p 3 -b | grep Bluetooth
Nov 13 22:57:00 bkeever-arch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected cc 0x2060 length: 1 < 7
Nov 13 22:57:00 bkeever-arch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x2060 failed: -38
Nov 13 22:57:03 bkeever-arch kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command tx timeout
```